# AES Decryption Using C#

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle

I am using a Java based configuration management tool called [Zuul](https://github.com/mcantrell/Zuul/wiki) which supports encrypting sensitive configuration information using various encryption schemes.

I have configured it to use below scheme for my data

**AES (Bouncy Castle)**

- Name: PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
- Requirements: Bouncy Castle API and JCE Unlimited Strength Policy Files
- Hashing Algorithm: SHA256
- Hashing Iterations: 1000

Now when reading my configuration data back, I need to decrypt the information before I can use it and the documentation provides below information around this topic.

The encrypted values produced by Jasypt (and thus Zuul) are are prefixed with the salt (usually 8 or 16 bytes depending on the algorithm requirements). They are then Base64 encoded. Decrypting the results goes something like this:

- Convert the Base64 string to bytes
- Strip off the first 8 or 16 bytes as the salt
- Keep the remaining bytes for the encrypted payload
- Invoke the KDF function with the salt, iteration count and the password to create the secret key.
- Use the secret key to decrypt the encrypted payload

More details here: [Zull Encryption wiki](https://github.com/mcantrell/Zuul/wiki/Encryption)

Based on above details, I have written below code (and my knowledge around security is very limited)

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipher, string password)
{
   const int saltLength = 16;
   const int iterations = 1000;

   byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);
   byte[] saltBytes = cipherBytes.Take(saltLength).ToArray();
   byte[] encryptedBytes = cipherBytes.Skip(saltLength).ToArray();

   Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, iterations);
   byte[] keyBytes = key.GetBytes(16);

   AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
   aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
   aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;

   aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
   aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);

   ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
   MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
   CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
   StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);

   return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I configured Zuul to use below password for the encryption

> SimplePassword

And now I have an encrypted string given to me by Zuul and I need to decrypt it

> p8C9hAHaoo0F25rMueT0+u0O6xYVpGIkjHmWqFJmTOvpV8+cipoDFIUnaOFF5ElQ

When I try to decrypt this string using above code, I get below exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

As I mentioned earlier, my knowledge around this topic is limited and I am not able to figure out if the information provided in the documentation is not enough, if I am doing something wrong while writing the decryption routine or should I be using bouncy castle for decryption as well.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to Bouncy Castle for decryption instead since that is used by Zuul as well.

Here is the code that works

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipher, string password)
{
   const int saltLength = 16;
   const int iterations = 1000;
   const string algSpec = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
   const string algName = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";

   byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);
   byte[] saltBytes = cipherBytes.Take(saltLength).ToArray();
   byte[] encryptedBytes = cipherBytes.Skip(saltLength).ToArray();
   char[] passwordChars = password.ToCharArray();

   Asn1Encodable defParams = PbeUtilities.GenerateAlgorithmParameters(algName, saltBytes, iterations);
   IWrapper wrapper = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper(algSpec);
   ICipherParameters parameters = PbeUtilities.GenerateCipherParameters(algName, passwordChars, defParams);
   wrapper.Init(false, parameters);

   byte[] keyText = wrapper.Unwrap(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);

   return Encoding.Default.GetString(keyText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Zuul documentation they are deriving both key and iv from the password/salt.
So you should derive 256+128 bits (i.e. 48 bytes), and use first 32 bytes as the key, and next 16 bytes as IV.
And this should be done in one operation, not as consequent calls to key.DeriveBytes.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nickolay, now I understand the significance of Key and Block sizes. I updated the code according to your suggestion, but still getting the same error.

Highlighted below are the lines that I changed

Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, iterations);
**byte[] keyBytes = key.GetBytes(48);**

AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aesAlg.KeySize = 256;
aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;

**aesAlg.Key = keyBytes.Take(aesAlg.KeySize / 8).ToArray();**
**aesAlg.IV = keyBytes.Skip(aesAlg.KeySize / 8).ToArray();**

Comment: The next thing to try would be to set padding to None and see if decryption produces something which looks like correct data.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nickolay, I have set the padding to none by adding this line **aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;** which doesn't cause my code to fail anymore, but the decrypted value is some random characters :(

Comment: Okay, the next thing I found only now is that Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses SHA1, while you obviously need SHA256. And please also check encryption mode, if it defaults to CBC in AesCryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: You are right Nickolay, I however wasn't able to figure out a way to derive a key using SHA256. I have changed my code to use Bouncy Castle instead and it all works perfect. I will post the code for everyone's reference as well. Thanks for all the help and suggestions.